# Normal open file statement in VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I´m trying to open a file but it´s not working.

```
Workbook.Open C:\users\me\desktop\testfile.txt
```

I always get the error message: Run-time error '424': Object required

I just want to open a file. It´s not fixed if the file will be a exel, a txt, jpg or word file.

Should be as simple as possible.

Comment: `Workbook.Open "C:\users\me\desktop\testfile.txt"`

Comment: Same error message. Maybe I have to add some special reference?

Comment: Sorry just checked it further. The correct syntax is `Workbooks.Open "C:\users\me\desktop\testfile.xls"` but you can only open a workbook this way, see here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx What do you want to do with the file you open?

Comment: I get the same error message. I save this file before and this procedure should just open the file for reading.

Comment: For a better understanding, I have a access database with a form which shows some questions for every question you have to give an answer. To make sure your answer is not just created by yourself you can add an document or picture where your answer is based on. But if you want to read this file you have to reopen it and this is the point where I get this error message.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To open a word, excel, jpg, pdf or any file, simple use:

```
Application.FollowHyperlink "path to file name"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was searching for! Just open a file even if it´s a txt, xlsx, doc or something else. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Create an Excel object first:

```
Dim xl as New Excel.Application

xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\users\me\desktop\testfile.txt")
xl.Visible = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to open the text file in excel ..

Then use [opentext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195814%28v=office.11%29.aspx) function

**example**

```
Workbooks.OpenText ("C:\users\me\desktop\testfile.txt")
```